# Need help decrypting my assembly program

Tags: c++, assembly

I have this encryption program in C++ and ASM which has got encryption routines but I need to know 
how the decryption routine for it should look like .
This is the code  :

```
//-ENCRYPTION ROUTINES 

void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{   char temp_char;             

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    
    {   temp_char = OChars [i];     
        __asm {             
            push   eax      
            push   ecx      
            movzx  ecx,temp_char     
            lea    eax,EKey      
            call   encrypt       
            mov    temp_char,al  
            pop    ecx      
            pop    eax      
        }
        EChars [i] = temp_char;         
    }
   return;

    // --- Start of Assembly code
   __asm {

    encrypt5: push eax 
          mov  al,byte ptr [eax]
      push ecx 
          and eax,0x7C 
          ror eax,1 
          ror eax,1 
          inc eax 
          mov edx,eax 
          pop ecx
      pop eax
      mov byte ptr [eax],dl
          xor edx,ecx 
          mov eax,edx 
          rol al,1 
          ret 

    encrypt:
        mov eax,ecx     
        inc eax         
        ret
    }

    //--- End of Assembly code
}
```

Comment: What have you got thus far?

Comment: its a simple bytewise char = (char+1)%256. Now you can reverse it...

Comment: This is basically all I have got for the code , so I just need to basically know how to reverse the assembly code which is shown below the " // --- Start of Assembly code "  in the code .

Answer (score 0):

The best clue ever for decryption (and as general as the question):

undo everything

I guess every instruction in that code has an conservative opposite (unless it's destroyin the data, but hey)

So if the code ends with:

```
inc eax
ret
```

You start with

```
[load the return in eax]
dec eax
```

and so on.

Comment: Can also anybody tell about some of the comments of the code , because there are some codes that I just dont get like   ror eax,1     as well as   mov byte ptr [eax],dl

Comment: Hmm... So you don't get much of assembly? It's gonna be a longer then expected road (but ain't it always?). I don't mean to sound no-polite,  but maybe you should study it a bit more before going further.

This is a good reference http://www.jegerlehner.ch/intel/IntelCodeTable.pdf

Comment: (hhmmm... can't you throw every possible char at the code and save the output?) (and then for decrypt just use that table?)